# Using blob as a JSON data feed

Tags: json, azure

As Azure blob storage is a very cheap data storage solution, would it make sense to store JSON data in blobs so clients can access it like a data API? This way we don't need to spin up Web Apps/APIs to server JSON data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could work, depending on the scenario. The blobs will be updated on-the-fly when you push a new version of the JSON files.

I demonstrated this a while ago with a simple app that uploads and updates a file. Clients could target the URL and for them is seemed like they were accessing a JSON data feed that kept being updated.